# A Nice, Simple Web Scraping Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, internet

**Introduction**

This is a web scraping Code Golf challenge that attempts to take stock Name and price columns from the 'Most Active' list on this [New York Times URL](https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp).

**Why is this challenge interesting?**

Challenge:
Scrape these figures from this NYT page and turn it into a data frame using the smallest number of bytes possible (IE: `import pandas as pd` (should you choose to use Python) would give you a score of 19 (19 bytes). The data frame must be printed or returned as output.

[image]

Shortest Code by bytes wins the challenge. That's it!

Input:

> ```
> import requests
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> import pandas as pd
>
> url='https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp'
>
> def pull_active(url):
>     # your code
>     response = requests.get(url)
>     if response.status_code == 200:
>       print("Response Successful")
>     else:
>       print("Response Unsuccessful")
>       return()
>     bs_object = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
>     st_value = bs_object.find_all('td',class_='colPrimary')
>     st_name = bs_object.find_all('a',class_="truncateMeTo1")
>     x = []
>     y = []
>     for tag in st_name:
>       x.append(tag.get_text())
>     for tag in st_value:
>       y.append(tag.get_text())
>     data = {'Name': x[0:8],
>             'Price': y[0:8]}
>     df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>     return(df)
> pull_active(url)
> ```

Score: 773 bytes
To beat it, any code under 773 bytes.

Output:

> ```
>   Name    Price
> 0 General Electric Co 10.11
> 1 Advanced Micro Devices Inc  33.13
> 2 PG&E Corp   6.14
> 3 Fiat Chrysler Automobiles NV    14.98
> 4 Neuralstem Inc  1.83
> 5 AT&T Inc    38.20
> 6 GrubHub Inc 34.00
> 7 Twitter Inc 29.86
> ```

...

Comment: Language restrictions like "Only responses coded in Python, please" are generally discouraged on this site.

Comment: Fair enough-- I'm still relatively new. I'll modify the post to encourage more participation.

Comment: Also, great! I'll reflect that as well.

Comment: Is this JavaScript answer valid? Open browser's console in same page and use this code in console: `document.querySelector('tbody').innerText`

Comment: Or even shorter since jQuery is already available in that page: `$('tbody')[0].innerText`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/), 73

```
lynx -dump http://nyti.ms/2BY72Ph|grep -Po '\[(1[6-9]|2[0-3])]\K[^.]*...'
```

Output is as follows:

```
General Electric Co          10.11
Advanced Micro Devices Inc   33.13
PG&E Corp                    6.14 
Fiat Chrysler Automobiles NV 14.98
Neuralstem Inc               1.83 
AT&T Inc                     38.20
GrubHub Inc                  34.00
Twitter Inc                  29.86
```

Comment: @RobinRyder, somehow I'd always missed that paragraph before now.

Comment: @640KB It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 97 bytes

```r
library(rvest)
matrix(html_text(html_nodes(html("http://nyti.ms/2BY72Ph"),"td"))[2:25],,3,T)[,-3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjqCy1uESTKzexpCizQiOjJDcnviS1ogTCystPSS0GMzWUMkpKCqz09fMqSzL1cov1jZwizY0CMpQ0dZRKUpQ0NaONrIxMY3V0jHVCNKN1dI1j//8HAA)

Gets all the `td` elements of the page. We want elements 2 to 25, which gives everything we need plus the `% change`, which is removed by omitting the 3rd column of the final matrix.

Outputs as a character matrix, since this is less bytes than a data frame:

```r
     [,1]                  [,2]   
[1,] "General Electric Co" "10.11"
[2,] "PG&E Corp"           "6.14" 
[3,] "Neuralstem Inc"      "1.83" 
[4,] "GrubHub Inc"         "34.00"
[5,] "Twitter Inc"         "29.86"
[6,] "Zynga Inc"           "6.21" 
[7,] "Iveric Bio Inc"      "3.56" 
[8,] "Pfizer Inc"          "38.48"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>154</del> <del>153</del> 130 bytes

```php
foreach(DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile('http://nyti.ms/2BY72Ph')->getElementsByTagName(td)as$i)$x<24&&print$x++%3?"$i->nodeValue ":"
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctNC4IwGADge78ixvIDMcGCYImCWHTI8iBBx6FvbjC3oa@gv97q8tweK@yaZPbnxwzAG@EVz7IwzdSDRsaU4e2tLu9XqcBzBaJlUaQXlPt@jOL8fYor4fph2gFeFPzPmC817x68Bw9bn49U@nRO4qPj2EFqpHMQ7A4ZoTJMtWnhxdUEW8LIhpzX9Qs)

*-23 bytes* thx to @Night2!

```php
$ php nyt.php

Agile Therapeutics Inc 1.38
Advanced Micro Devices Inc 34.05
Facebook Inc 191.82
Kraft Heinz Co 32.34
Sirius XM Holdings Inc 6.72
Apple Inc 247.40
Zynga Inc 6.24
Snap Inc 15.11
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>271</s> <s>257</s> <s>251</s> 233 bytes

```fs
 let l=HtmlDocument.Load("http://nyti.ms/2BY72Ph").Descendants["td"]|>Seq.filter(fun n->n.HasClass("colText")||n.HasClass("colPrimary"))|>Seq.take 16|>Seq.map(fun n->n.InnerText())|>Seq.toList
 [for i in 0..7-> l.[i*2]+" "+l.[i*2+1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBPS8NAEMXv@RTDgpBYuv1zsCAmB1ulQg/FepGQw5JMzOLubNydioF@95imUME5vXm89zu8OkxL57F3LRIcusBoo1E/HxrlW7lRrKLIIEMDaQ9nYdItW7Nx5dEisdw5VcWiYW7vZzPqWEsbZsvH99Vy34hEbjCUSJUiDrngShSn7IBfstaG0cf1kYCmGcmtCmujQohF6cwb/rBITqd/9t5rq3wnkuTCYPWJsLi7PFa1f7QXIvRnSnzNup0OHEFeOw8aNMFcytU0AyNzfbssJgLE5KIni6Lo84cnYt/tnSbOinEAq4aW8h/fkEYw3NnzGI6GIYVmtK7wBioHrR/KNYG4CQL0GFg7Cs6gfMVhtGS05v0v)